# How to conditionally render CSS and JavaScript inside head element of an HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to use two different styles for two different looks of a page and I need different CSS and JavaScript files for that. Is there anyway I could conditionally render CSS and JavaScript files inside the `head` element in an html file?

I am working on an AngularJS application with Angular UI-Router module.

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>

    <!-- if {{$state.current.name}} is "front" then list these CSS files -->
    <!-- if {{$state.current.name}} is "admin" then list these CSS files -->

  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- ... -->
    <!-- if {{$state.current.name}} is "front" then list these JavaScript files -->
    <!-- if {{$state.current.name}} is "admin" then list these JavaScript files -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Could somebody help me with it?

Comment: Are `ng-if` and `ng-src` of any help?  As in, `<link ng-if="condition" rel="stylesheet" ng-src="style.css">` and similar for scripts?  Just an idea.

Comment: @idrarig: Could I not have a list of `<link>` elements based on a condition rather than having `ng-if` on every `<link>` element? Could I have two `<head>` elements and render only one of them based on `<head ng-if="condition">.. </head>`? Would it be valid html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I played around a bit and came up with [this gist](https://gist.github.com/idrarig/dfb028d5cbfb377313c5).  From `index.html` you can see that what you want can be achieved using the ngIf, ngSrc, and ngHref directives as I suggested in my comment.  From `index-grouped.html` you can see that you can indeed group `<link>` and `<script>` tags that need to appear under the same condition, but I'm not sure whether my approach works cross-browser.  I only tried Google Chrome.

Anyway, having two `<head>` elements is not valid HTML.  You can verify this yourself using [an online validator](http://validator.w3.org).

I hope this helps.